# Cast Varchar to Interval data type

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement to store interval data type in a table.
Since interval data type is not directly supported as a column type in Table, the type of the column has been set as Varchar. in that case how can I cast this varchar datatype to interval data type in my query.

The below would give you a picture of what is needed.

```
Create Table tablename1
(
col1 varchar(15)
);

Insert into Tablename1 values ('12:00:00');

select current_date + cast(col1 as hour to minute); << this statement would fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the interval keyword: **cast(col1 as interval hour to second)**

But you can't add an interval to a date, only to a timestamp:

```
select current_timestamp(0) + cast(col1 as interval hour to second)
```

Btw, of course INTERVALs are supported datatypes in Teradata.

```
Create Table tablename1
(
col1 interval hour(4) to second
);

select current_timestamp(0) + col1
```

Comment: I wish I can upvote this answer a thousand times :).